# many2many create method error: unhashable type: 'list' Odoo 17.0

Tags: odoo-17

I'm trying to import slack channels into odoo but the above mentioned error arises. I am trying to populate a many2many field. I tried to pass tuple into it but got no luck. If anyone has any suggestions,do reply. While debugging, I realized that the error occurs when the ORM methods like write or create gets triggered.
Following is my line of code which I believe is the reason behind this error:
`'channel_partner_ids': [(6, 0, tuple(total_partner_ids))]`

Answer (score 0):

In your case `total_partner_ids` is already a list. And if I translate your code, it look like this

```
'channel_partner_ids': [(6, 0, ([1,2,3,4,...],))]
```

But if you look the Odoo documentation the magic number 6 work like this :

```
(6, 0, [IDs])          replace the list of linked IDs (like using (5) then (4,ID) for each ID in the list of IDs)
```

To resolve your code, you must remove the tuple function called.

```
'channel_partner_ids': [(6, 0, total_partner_ids)]
```